# In Polymer how do I define a class in a parent element and use it in a child element?

Tags: polymer

I am trying to figure out how I can define a dynamic class in a parent element, then set the name of the class on a property of a client element and then have the client element use the style for something.

So what options do I have?

Cheers

The example I am trying to beat into shape is here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js'></script>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'>
</head>
<body unresolved>
    <dom-module id='my-element'>
        <style>
            /* Here is where I would like to dynamically add this 
                .somerandomname {
                    @apply(--the-class);
                }
                where 'somerandomname' is just some name tying to together with the div below
            */
            .somerandomname {
                @apply(--the-class);
            }
        </style>
        <template>
            <!--
                Below the class will actually be class$ allowing data binding to the somerandomname

                A note here is that there will be many tags that needs mixins and I do not know in advance
                what they are called, but the data provided to the custom element includes the class that should 
                be used for the tag
            -->
            <div class='somerandomname'>Show me the color</div>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-element',

            properties: {
                myclass: {
                    type: String,
                    value: ''
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

    <dom-module id='base-page'>
        <style>
            my-element {
                --the-class: {
                    background-color: red;
                };
            }
        </style>
        <template>
            <my-element myclass='--the-class'></my-element>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'base-page'
        });
    </script>
    <base-page></base-page>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm guessing your children elements are also custom elements, in that case, you should make css classes in the parent element that define values for css custom properties or mixins that apply to the children

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for your comment, much appreciated. Yes, I am tryting to use mixins and have updated my question above. But I am kind of stuck here. I have written a couple of questions in the example above. My problem in essence is how I dynamically can apply not only a style, but also the name of the style to the inners of a child custom element. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're a bit confused about how mixins and custom css properties, I hope this helps with that.

First of all, you don't really need any Polymer properties to make this thing work, so, the `myclass` property in `my-element`'s definition isn't really needed for this.

Considering that, you naturally don't need the `myclass="--the-class"` bit either, everything should work fine without those two things.

Then again, bear in mind that since you defined in `base-page`'s style that all `my-element` children will have that mixin applied to them it

Here's a slightly modified version of your code which should illustrate how the mixins are applied (and here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufzqvu8c/2/) for it)

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      .customized {
        @apply(--customized-div);
      }
    </style>
    <div class="customized">
      This div is customized
    </div>
    <div>
      This div isn't customized
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="base-page">
  <template>
    <style>
      my-element { /*This applies to all my-element children*/
        --customized-div: {
          color: red;
        };
      }
      my-element.green { /*This only applies to those with the green class*/
        --customized-div: {
          color: green;
        };
      }
    </style>
    Child 1
    <my-element></my-element>
    <br>
    Child 2
    <my-element class="green"></my-element>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
      is: 'my-element'
  });

  Polymer({
      is: 'base-page'
  });
</script>
<base-page></base-page>
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks a lot for your comment :-). There is a slight twist to the problem which was not clear. Inside of the child element I will dynamically create items that refer the classes and the class names are provided as part of data to the child element and need to match the mixins, which is what I was trying to illustrate with the myclass property. So in other words, I do not know beforehand that there is a "customized" class that should be Applied and that is why I am trying to dynamically inject the class through the mixins, but then also dynamically add and use it in the child element

Comment: So basically, you want the child element to be able to have multiple children which have different styles which are all defined dynamically?

Comment: Yes. The class names are provided to the child and set in the parent